# Ajax result print [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, object, object-to-string

I want to receive data using ajax. But when use this code, result prints [object HTMLInputElement]. Can I change object to string?

Here's My code in JSP what use ajax.

```
$('select#product').change(function() {

        var param = "code=" + $('#product').val();

        $.ajax({
            url : 'add_products/add_products.jsp',
            contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data : param,
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                $('#color').val(color);
                $('#price').val(price);
            }
        });
    });
...
<td>
    <input type="text" id="color" class="form-control" name="color"  />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="price" class="form-control" name="price" value="0"  />
</td>
```

And This is add_products.jsp what receive the upper jsp.

```
product_code = request.getParameter("code");

try {
    query = "select * from new_product where product_code='"+product_code+"'";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        size = rs.getString("sizes");
        color = rs.getString("color");
        price = rs.getString("price_cny");

        out.println(color);
        out.println(price);

    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    out.println(e);
} finally {
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(data) to convert object to string in jquery.

Comment: Where in this code do you print results?  "result prints"

Comment: @bassxzero My result is "data", but I want to receive data is two. So I tried no result variable(data) but "color", "price"

Comment: @Ila HI Ila:) I am trying to what you say, but result is "{}". Can I ask you why?

Comment: console.log(data) or like lla said stringify

Comment: Are you sure that "param" is being passed correctly from your ajax to the server variable "code" ?

Comment: @bassxzero Yes. Because I did debugging and saw the "color", "price". The problem is when "out.println" is one, for example just "out.println(color)", this display well. but when "out.println"is two, for example like my code, there has error like my asking.

Comment: @Dayoung just to clarify, you are saying that when you return 1 value from the server everything works, but when you return multiple values from the server you don't get the correct data?

Comment: @bassxzero Exactly! I want to return muliple values.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your server code to this...

```
product_code = request.getParameter("code");

try {
    query = "select * from new_product where product_code='"+product_code+"'";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        size = rs.getString("sizes");
        color = rs.getString("color");
        price = rs.getString("price_cny");

        out.println(color+"_"+price);                //concatenate 2 values

    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    out.println(e);
} finally {
}
```

And your client code to this...

```
$('select#product').change(function() {

        var param = "code=" + $('#product').val();

        $.ajax({
            url : 'add_products/add_products.jsp',
            contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data : param,
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                var values = data.split("_");       //get your 2 values seperated
                $('#color').val(values[0]);
                $('#price').val(values[1]);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you veryvery much Shrinivas Shukla:)

Answer (score 0):

I have never coded in JSP so be kind.
Try this. It is based on this example. http://codesstore.blogspot.com/2011/12/json-with-jquery-jsp-servlets.html

Basically you want to find a way to return a json object.

Ajax

```
$('select#product').change(function() {

  var param = "code=" + $('#product').val();

  $.ajax({
    url : 'add_products/add_products.jsp',
    contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    data : param,
    type : 'POST',            
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

      try {
        $result = $.parseJSON(data);
      }
      catch(error)
      {
        alert('Error parsing json ' + data);
      }

      alert(data.color);
      alert(data.price);

    }
  });
});
```

JSP

Make sure you import for json support.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;  
product_code = request.getParameter("code");

try {
    query = "select * from new_product where product_code='"+product_code+"'";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();  

    while (rs.next()) {
        size = rs.getString("sizes");
        color = rs.getString("color");
        price = rs.getString("price_cny");

        json.put("color", color);  
        json.put("pr", price);  
    }

       out.println(json);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    out.println(e);
} finally {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this updates. In ajax, success block:

```
success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
     $('#color').val(data.color);
     $('#price').val(data.price);
}
```

***add_products.jsp***:

At this line at the top of jsp.

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Output jdbc result as:

```
out.print("{");
if (rs.next()) {//note, replaced with while loop
    out.print("\"sizes\":" + rs.getString("sizes") + ",");
    out.print("\"color\":" + rs.getString("color") + ",");
    out.print("\"price\":" + rs.getString("price_cny"));
}
out.print("}");
```